# how to move exe.config to custom location

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a console app which hosts my wcf services and takes their configuration from app.config (whick then becomes .exe.config). Now i want to move it to {OutputDirectory}/conf. How now can i tell my app to search the config there? I tried to write like this:

```
private const string CONFIG_FOLDER = "conf\\";
private const string CONFIG_FILENAME = "MyApp.exe.config";

var configPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, CONFIG_FOLDER, CONFIG_FILENAME);
var config = new ExeConfigurationFileMap {ExeConfigFilename = configPath};
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(config, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But i still get an Exception:

> Additional information: Service 'LinProgWebServer.ClientService' has
>   zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   service element matching the service name could be found in the
>   configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the
>   service element.

What am i doing wrong?

I'll by gratefull for any help

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1838960/2132796) answer.

Comment: Thanks, found answer ;)