# Load parts of App.Config from a webService

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cloud, app-config

Imagine a highly distributed system with same self-hosted WCF services on different machines. It's a pain to manage all App.Config files in a decentralized way.

I am sure there is a solution to load one Config section or a key value setting from some custom web-service, but I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relocating app.config file to a custom path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838619/relocating-app-config-file-to-a-custom-path)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question is about loading app.config from shared storage o locally

Answer (score 1):

You can read the configurations from the  section in your appConfig through

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key)
```

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager has other configuration accessors, for example

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name]
```

For documentation see https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: But the point of the question is to get it from a web service, not from local App.config)

Comment: You want to app.config file to come from a web.service? Or the configurations contained within (i..e loaded by the web.service and sent to the calling application)?

Comment: Ideally -  parts of app.config  come from some external source like webservice.

Comment: Bootstrapping the config file is not advised. It is an application-level configuration, and a change to the file would make e.g. IIS restart the related website. 

You are better off extracting the relevant parts of the config by your dedicated service and forward those to services on the machines at which they are needed.

Comment: And how would've you advised to handle this scenario: repoint 3 services on 10 machines to different database and restart them?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://serverfault.com/questions/127409/iis-configuration-synchronization-for-web-server-farm

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that they are self-hosted :) Right now I am looking at systems like Salt, Ansible, Puppet, but I don't know if they are suited for this kind of task