# Windows Application Packaging Project

Tags: c#, wpf, msix

I can't get the windows application packaging project add my `sqlite.db` file.

I have an application in WPF and I am trying to package it using windows application packaging project. my application uses sqlite, but when the project compiles and I install the app with the generated installer, it tells me that the sqlite db file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you extracted the MSIX package to see if the db is actually missing? Maybe the error is not clear enough.

Please note that files installed by an MSIX package in the WindowsApps system folder are read-only. If you want your app to write in the DB make sure you place it under the AppData folder.

[How to allow for editable .Net generated config files with MSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296427/how-to-allow-for-editable-net-generated-config-files-with-msix/65307757#65307757)